# Where can I locate LAMP

Tags: lamp

I am a complete novice.
How can I locate LAMP on my computer?

Comment: See this URL in your browser: `http://localhost` for apache (aka. the website set up after installing LAMP)

Comment: In general: learn what dpkg -l, dpkg -S and dpkg -L do , this helps greatly in "finding where the #&&%&%!! stuff I just installed went" ;)

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 19):

LAMP is a set of programs. It stands for:

- Linux  (Operating system)
- Apache (Webserver)
- MySQL  (Database)
- PHP    (Programming language)

So LAMP isn't a single thingie you can find, but a combination of applications installed on your system... and even IS your system (the L for Linux part)

Comment: This still doesn't provide an answer to the question. You should put *how* to find them (i.e, `dpkg` and its options).

Comment: @cybermonkey .. this provides the answer that LAMP isn't a single item you can find on your Ubuntu system, and what the acronym stands for. This is a nice offset to discover and learn about Ubuntu.

Comment: ..which *isn't* something that the question asked. The question asked `how can I locate it?`, *not* `what is it?`. **You need to answer the question.**

Answer (score 0):

To install LAMP on Ubuntu Server using the GUI, you would use the command:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Then you would highlight the LAMP option and press space to confirm selection.

*To install it easier with only the shell you would use this command:*

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```